# git - how to clean up a complex branch before merging into master?

Tags: git, merge

Normally I `git rebase -i master` before merging a branch into master to squash or fixup little commits (e.g. the commit message is just "refactor"), but what can I do with larger, more complex branches that have had both master and children merged in at various stages? I believe rebase works for this simple scenario (based on googling):

```
  * (newest commit)
  |\
  * |
  | * grandchild
  * |
  |/
  * child
  |
 / 
|
* master (oldest commit)
```

But what about this one?

```
  *  (newest commits)
  |\
  * |
 /| * grandchild
* * |
| |/
| * child
* |
|/ 
|
* master (oldest commit)
```

Is there a way to simplify this history without a large amount of effort? I tried just `git rebase -i master` and there are lots of conflicts (some of which are blank thanks to `rerere` I assume, but some are tricky to resolve). To be clear, this is my desired result (clearly we can just run a catch up merge in master and we'll have a linear history; final number of commits in child branch is arbitrary):

```
  * (newest commit)
  |
  * child
  |
 / 
|
* master (oldest commit, though newest in master)
```

My apologies if this is a duplicate question, as it likely is (but I can't find one that addresses my issue specifically).

Comment: Have you tried `rebase -i` in this case?

Comment: You need to use `rebase -i` and drop the useless commits (keep the modification when solving conflicts)

Comment: @JoshLee Yes--lots of conflicts even with rerere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options.

First, `rebase -i` will *probably* work.  It's worth a try - this is git, so you can get back to your previous state if need be.  (If you're on `branch-X` when you start the rebase, and it all goes wrong, you know that (a) rebase only changes the `branch-X` ref, and (b) the reflog can be used to move it back, so

```
git reset --hard branch-X@{1}
```

and no harm is done.)

Now if that fails in some particular way, or seems too difficult to get right, that's a more informed (and IMO better) starting place for a question.

That said, off the bat I think for this particular case it might be easier to do

```
git checkout child
git merge --squash branch-X
git commit
git branch -f branch-X
```

as a "squash merge" is all about replacing whatever topology would be involved in a merge with a single commit.

Be aware that either way - indeed *any* way you go about doing this - the best practices would say not to do it if the commits you're replacing have been pushed to remote.  This is usually stated as a caveat about rebasing, but it applies to any operation that modifies history.

Comment: I've gone back and forth on whether to phrase the merge command as `git merge --squash branch-X` or `git merge --squash newest-commit`; should be the same result

Comment: I am currently on `child` and getting " (nothing to squash)Already up-to-date.  " from git. I think this must be the right track though.

Comment: I did create a new branch off of master though and `git merge --squash child` did work. Nice!

Comment: Based on that, I suspect the issue is with the "imprecise" way we're identifying which commit to have checked out vs. which one to name in the merge/squash command.  Sounds like you got it working, anyway